# general serial (ttl) programming question (not language specific)

Tags: serial-port, ttl

I'm writing an app with two arduinos and an RF transceiver connecting them. The arduinos are doing calculations etc in a loop with a 50ms second delay.

The transceiver operates at a baud rate of 1200.

My question is, because of the fast loop there could be a lot of data transmitted quickly, most are just short values such as "P25500" during the 50ms loop. During a full second the number of sent characters might be around 200.

I'm new to wireless ttl and transceivers and I'm not sure what limitations are with 1200 baud and how much data I could send per second before losses occur.

Can someone let me know if I'd be safe with this?

Comment: Depending the encoding, 1200 baud is 1200 bits/second.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud.  200 characters is (with delays and stop bits) 2000 bits.   Is this what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending the encoding, 1200 baud is 1200 bits/second.

200 characters is (with delays and stop bits) about 2000 bits.

This is pretty well-defined stuff.  "I'm not sure what limitations are with 1200 baud" should be covered very nicely in numerous on-line resources.

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud

Then read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitrate